# Finding index of values in a list dynamically

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am having two lists as follows:

```
list_1
['A-1','A-1','A-1','A-2','A-2','A-3']

list_2
['iPad','iPod','iPhone','Windows','X-box','Kindle']
```

I would like to split the `list_2` based on the index values in `list_1`. For instance,

```
list_a1
['iPad','iPod','iPhone']

list_a2
['Windows','X-box']

list_a3
['Kindle']
```

I know index method, but it needs the value to be matched to be passed along with. In this case, I would like to dynamically find the indexes of the values in list_1 with the same value. Is this possible? Any tips/hints would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `list_1` guaranteed to be sorted (such that all the occurrences of each index value appear in a row)?

Comment: Yes...list_1 values are ordered...all A-1's first, then A-2 and so on...and the values in list_2 follows the respective order in list_1

Comment: Thank you for the answers...one of the few moments when I want to select both the answers...:-)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this.

I'd do it by using `zip` and `groupby`.

First:

```
>>> list(zip(list_1, list_2))
[('A-1', 'iPad'),
 ('A-1', 'iPod'),
 ('A-1', 'iPhone'),
 ('A-2', 'Windows'),
 ('A-2', 'X-box'),
 ('A-3', 'Kindle')]
```

Now:

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> [(key, list(group)) for key, group in 
...  itertools.groupby(zip(list_1, list_2), operator.itemgetter(0))]
[('A-1', [('A-1', 'iPad'), ('A-1', 'iPod'), ('A-1', 'iPhone')]),
 ('A-2', [('A-2', 'Windows'), ('A-2', 'X-box')]),
 ('A-3', [('A-3', 'Kindle')])]
```

So, you just want each `group`, ignoring the `key`, and you only want the second element of each element in the `group`. You can get the second element of each group with another comprehension, or just by unzipping:

```
>>> [list(zip(*group))[1] for key, group in
...  itertools.groupby(zip(list_1, list_2), operator.itemgetter(0))]
[('iPad', 'iPod', 'iPhone'), ('Windows', 'X-box'), ('Kindle',)]
```

I would personally find this more readable as a sequence of separate iterator transformations than as one long expression. Taken to the extreme:

```
>>> ziplists = zip(list_1, list_2)
>>> pairs = itertools.groupby(ziplists, operator.itemgetter(0))
>>> groups = (group for key, group in pairs)
>>> values = (zip(*group)[1] for group in groups)
>>> [list(value) for value in values]
```

… but a happy medium of maybe 2 or 3 lines is usually better than either extreme.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.izip_longest` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, izip_longest
>>> inds = [next(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(list_1), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

First group items of `list_1` and find the starting index of each group:

```
>>> inds
[0, 3, 5]
```

Now use slicing and `izip_longest` as we need pairs `list_2[0:3]`, `list_2[3:5]`, `list_2[5:]`:

```
>>> [list_2[x:y] for x, y in izip_longest(inds, inds[1:])]
[['iPad', 'iPod', 'iPhone'], ['Windows', 'X-box'], ['Kindle']]
```

To get a list of dicts you can something like:

```
>>> inds = [next(g) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(list_1), key=lambda x:x[1])]
>>> {k: list_2[ind1: ind2[0]] for (ind1, k), ind2 in
                                   zip_longest(inds, inds[1:], fillvalue=[None])}
{'A-1': ['iPad', 'iPod', 'iPhone'], 'A-3': ['Kindle'], 'A-2': ['Windows', 'X-box']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually I'm the one rushing to a `groupby` solution ;^) but here I'll go the other way and manually insert into an `OrderedDict`:

```
list_1 = ['A-1','A-1','A-1','A-2','A-2','A-3']
list_2 = ['iPad','iPod','iPhone','Windows','X-box','Kindle']

from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for code, product in zip(list_1, list_2):
    d.setdefault(code, []).append(product)
```

produces a `d` looking like

```
>>> d
OrderedDict([('A-1', ['iPad', 'iPod', 'iPhone']), 
             ('A-2', ['Windows', 'X-box']), ('A-3', ['Kindle'])])
```

with easy access:

```
>>> d["A-2"]
['Windows', 'X-box']
```

and we can get the list-of-lists in `list_1` order using `.values()`:

```
>>> d.values()
[['iPad', 'iPod', 'iPhone'], ['Windows', 'X-box'], ['Kindle']]
```

If you've noticed that no one is telling you how to make a bunch of independent lists with names like `list_a1` and so on-- that's because that's a bad idea.  You want to keep the data together in something which you can (at a minimum) iterate over easily, and both dictionaries and list of lists qualify.

Comment: Great point in the last paragraph. Everyone else just assumed that instead of explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint
import collections

def main():
    list_1 = ['A-1','A-1','A-1','A-2','A-2','A-3']
    list_2 = ['iPad','iPod','iPhone','Windows','X-box','Kindle']

    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for list_1_element, list_2_element in zip(list_1, list_2):
        result[list_1_element].append(list_2_element)

    pprint.pprint(result)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you want simple code, it's not pretty, but gets the job done.

```
list_1 = ['A-1','A-1','A-1','A-2','A-2','A-3']
list_2 = ['iPad','iPod','iPhone','Windows','X-box','Kindle']
list_1a = []
list_1b = []
list_1c = []
place = 0
for i in list_1[::1]:
    if list_1[place] == 'A-1':
        list_1a.append(list_2[place])
    elif list_1[place] == 'A-2':
        list_1b.append(list_2[place])
    else:
        list_1c.append(list_2[place])
    place += 1
```